# Django csrf_protect decorator not working

Tags: django, vue.js, security, csrf

I am using Django to build a web app. I am using Vue JS for the frontend. My problem is when ever I use csrf_protect its showing 403 error

My views:

```
@csrf_protect
def SignUpView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username, password = form.cleaned_data.get('username'), form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            new_user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'Accounts/SignUp.html', {'form':form})  

@csrf_protect
def validateUsername(request):
    username = request.GET.get('username', None)
    usernameRegEx = r'^[a-zA-Z0-9@+-_.@]*$'
    usernameRegExResult = {
        'valid' : bool(re.search(usernameRegEx, username, re.M|re.I)),
        'is_taken' : User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()
    }

    return JsonResponse(usernameRegExResult)
```

I read the Django docs which says I can use csrf_protect decorator above my view but in my case its not working. Somebody please help.

Comment: I'm using React but I think this can still help. For me, I received the csrf value through cookies and tossed into my form's header, and it worked. [Check it out](https://gist.github.com/crimsonpython24/7c10845f6e6d72c9a4b0f5074d73883b)

Comment: If you require CSRF protection, you need to send a CSRF token with all requests. If you're sending those requests from Vue, that probably doesn't happen automagically and you would need to specifically consider how to propagate a valid CSRF token from Django to Vue and include that in the request.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF is a protection that prevents cross site request forgery. It works by generating an unique token that identify the form. So if you send data to your server without the token it gave you (through cookies for instance) it will not accept it.

If you have the CSRF middleware turned on you should not need CSRF protect decorator!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But now I have a new problem. Will you take a moment to help me with this? This is the link to the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62995845/django-csrf-token-does-not-work-in-mobile